# What does "the sacred and profane" possibly mean? and what's the meaning of the sentence?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

> Because the effluent crosses over the separation barrier between Israel and the West Bank, such a route would bridge the lives of Palestinians and Israelis. **The purified river, by collecting in its arid watershed the sacred and profane, would build help peace between the Middle East's two archenemies.**

I have no idea what this phase "**The purified river, by collecting in its arid watershed the sacred and profane, would build help peace between the Middle East's two archenemies.**" are talking about. Especially, the sacred and profane, even though I know all the definition.

source: National Geographic- December 2014: Out Of Eden Walk, Part Three

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer**

It's a metaphor for building peace in a region both "sacred and profane" by "making sacred" its "profanity," i.e., purifying the river.

**Long Answer**

> The purified river, by collecting in its arid watershed the sacred and profane, would help build peace between the Middle East’s two archenemies.
>
> "[Blessed. Cursed. Claimed. On foot through the Holy Lands](http://ngm.nationalgeographic.com/2014/12/pilgrim-roads/salopek-text)," Paul Salopek. *National Geographic Magazine*. December 2014.

Israel and Palestine are "the Middle East's two archenemies" in this context.

The land and the history of that land as "the birthplace of supreme deities" (ibid.), is "the sacred."

The river undergoing purification, "a river of raw sewage that foams in torrents" (ibid.), is "the profane."

And the project to "clean up the waste...and establish miles of “green” trails" (ibid.) is "the purified river."

Also, the Fertile Crescent, as [a part of the Middle East](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fertile_Crescent), is the "arid watershed."

And the arid watershed, by its mere location, has to "collect" whatever humans leave in it, including "the sacred and profane."

**Longer Answer**

What gives this sentence its depth (and beauty, if I may say so), however, is the literal meaning of the words sacred and profane used within this figurative context.

The profane is that which "violate[s] the sacred or the good," ("[Profane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profane)," Wikipedia).

Thus, to be sacred, one must remove the profane, through [purification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ritual_purification) ("Ritual purification," Wikipedia).

Thus, in an essay about one man's endeavor "to clean up the waste...and establish miles of “green” trails along a fabled valley where 5,000 years ago[,] ['a holy city in the three major Abrahamic religions of Judaism, Christianity and Islam' (1)] was founded" (2), it's quite apt to see the appearance of the words the sacred and the profane.

(1) "[Jerusalem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerusalem)," Wikipedia.

(2) "Blessed. Cursed. Claimed."

**Even Longer Answer**

And then, of course, there is the reason that this sentence is truly profound, and that is, of course, as a metaphor for the tumultuous region known as the Middle East.

The project to "clean up the waste...and establish miles of 'green' trails" ("Blessed. Cursed. Claimed.") is used by the author as a metaphor for peace.

And because the waste, the effluent, ironically, can cross borders [where people cannot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israeli_West_Bank_barrier#Reduced_freedoms) ("Israeli West Bank barrier, Reduced Freedoms," Wikipedia), the project hopes to "bridge the lives of Palestinians and Israelis" (ibid.) physically where politics cannot.

Quite a beautiful piece of writing. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: "profane" just means "not sacred" in this context. Note it refers to the purified river as collecting the profane, so it doesn't mean (just) the effluent. This is the better Wikipedia link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacred%E2%80%93profane_dichotomy

Comment: @OrangeDog. Hmmm, yes, I see what you mean.

Comment: @OrangeDog. Do you mind explaining why you think that link applies? Because I had tried to imagine this essay in that context at first, but at the end, I felt like I was forcing the explanation and so settled for the literal definitions of the words.

Comment: The literal definition is "not sacred". Common usage (e.g. "profanity") has more negative connotations. The literal interpretation of the phrase is that the land around the river (the arid watershed) will be occupied by both religious and secular activity. The mingling of the water in the river is a metaphor for the mingling of the Israeli and Palestinian peoples, Jewish, Muslim and Atheist, in peace.

Comment: @OrangeDog. I don't know. I'm OK with the second part of this comment, but the first part is a little shaky to me. Does "not sacred" (profane) necessarily mean secular? And I'm still not clear how the sacred and profane dichotomy applies? Perhaps I misunderstand the dichotomy when I see it to mean only group interests versus individual interests?

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang - I think OrangeDog's point is that "sacred and profane" is kind of a stock phrase, in the context of which "the profane" means "the stuff that is not sacred" (if you look up "profane", that's one of its definitions) and as such it doesn't quite mean the same thing as *obscene, dirty, violating*, etc.

Comment: "sacred and profane", "religious and secular", "spiritual and temporal" - all mean "everything"

Comment: Like *mundane*, *earthly*, or *wordly*, *profane* can have negative meanings, but as OrangeDog notes, it is neutral here, and *sacred* is not a reference to possession of virtue, but of a sanctiied purpose. In other words, *the sacred and the profane* is not equivalent to *the righteous and the wicked*, it is more like *the lay and the clergy*. It originated in theological discourse, but Nicean Christianity does not hold that earthly things are evil (this is characteristic of the Gnostics and Manicheans, whose influence on English is slight).

Comment: Could this sentence, anyway, be rewritten as "by collecting the sacred and profane in its arid watershed"?

Comment: and does collecting mean cleaning up in this case?

Comment: @jackbang, 1) Yes, it could. 2) Not really. More like "gathering" or "accumulating." It's the river that's collecting the sacred and profane; it's not cleaning itself up.